# Help regarding a core dump problem involving string class

Tags: c++, string, undefined-behavior

I am performing a code review for resolving a rarely occuring live enviornment problem. It is not reproducible in debug enviornments and hence the only means of investigation is the core dump from live enviornment and through code analysis. Here is the summary of the situation:
The core dump:

```
(gdb) bt
#0 in strlen () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string$base () from libstdc++.so.6
#2 in CustomStr::CustomStr()
```

The code has a wrapper class over the Std::String class, something like:

```
class CustomStr: public string
{
    //Some custom members here

};

This custom class has constructors:
CustomStr::CustomStr(const char *str):string(str)
{
   //Some derived class inits
}

CustomStr::CustomStr(const CustomStr& str) : string(str.c_str())
{
    //Some derived class inits   
}
```

I think both these constructors have a problem, if a pointer to NULL is passed on, the same will be passed to String constructor and when it internally calls strlen() to determine the length a Undefined Behavior(UB) will occur.
I think the correct way to implement will be to check for a NULL before calling the string constructor like:

```
CustomStr::CustomStr(const char *str)
{
   if(str!= NULL)
       string(str);
   //Some derived class inits
}

CustomStr::CustomStr(const CustomStr& str)
{
    if(str!= NULL)
       string(str.c_str());
    //Some derived class inits   
}
```

The Questions I have are:

1. Do the problem(which i think is) and the proposed solution seem a valid case?
2. Does string constructor check for NULL? I think It should because internally it calls strlen() which will show UB on NULL.
3. Apart from the NULL check How can one check if a valid const char* is being passed?(NOn NULL terminated const char* etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor from a const char* does not check for a null pointer, it is up to the caller to check if needed. YOU must know if it is possible or not for the argment to be null.

The other constructor could use string's copy constructor, instead of passing c_str() to it. It both saves you from recalculation the length, and also works for an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard requires that the pointer passed to `std::string(const char*)` not be a null pointer (§21.4.2 in c++0x draft n3092). So the string class itself will not check for that condition, and passing in a null means your code is not conforming.

You fix for the `CustomStr(const char*)` looks ok, but the one for `CustomStr(const std::string&)` is not. A reference cannot be null. (I'd be surprised if that compiled at all.)

There is now way to check if a random `char*` is a "valid" except for the null check.

Answer (score 1):

Further investigation of the core dump should give you a pretty exact picture of what's caused the crash. In particular, exactly what exception is being thrown? If it's an access violation (aka segfault), then the dump should also tell you precisely what faulty address is being accessed, which in turn will tell you whether your problem is a read from NULL pointer or something else.

It's certainly likely that a NULL pointer to the `std::string` consturctor could be your problem, but you shouldn't just assume that -- the purpose of a core dump is to take the guesswork out of such debugging.

In any case, yes, `std::string` just blows up if you construct it from a NULL pointer, and so you ought to NULL-check any pointers before you pass them into the string constructor. *eg*,

```
class CustomStr : public string
{
  CustomStr(const char *str) : string( str ? str : "<INVALID>" ) { .. }  
};
```

would be one simple workaround.

Comment: The idea behind this is that I, who never ever pass a null pointer :-), should not get a performance penalty from the check. You cannot impose it on everyone, just to save some newbies. If you need a check, you can add it yourself when calling the constructor.

Comment: For the curious, I did a whole one-hour conference lecture on core dumps just last week: http://bit.ly/hPCmVW

Comment: @Bo Persson: Sure, you could make the check be a debug-only assert, or just fire people who pass NULL pointers, or so on. The important thing is to look at the dump and be sure this really is the problem, not just assume.  (Although to be honest -- and I say this as my team's Official Perf Nazi -- the perf penalty of doing a NULL check in that case is very minimal, even on a RISC chip, because you can do it as a branchless conditional move in about three pipelined cycles.)

Comment: Yeah, but if you add three instructions to the std::string constructor, someone will publish a benchmark which "proves" that C++ is inherently slower than C. :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson: I know exactly the someone who'd do that. Though, again, if you're using `std::string`, you've lost the perf battle already. =P

Comment: @Bo Persson: I don't disagree with you -- I'm certainly never one to say no to better perf and I'd never tolerate needless NULL-checking in my app -- I was just trying to be clear in my example.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to std::string(const char*) should be a pointer to a \0-terminated string. NULL doesn't point to anything, and certainly not a null-terminated string. Therefore, it's a precondition violation to pass NULL.

A debug build should assert that the pointer isn't NULL, because `std::string` is a class that will be used by novices. It should not be checked at runtime, as no valid program passes NULL anyway.

As usual in C++, there's no way to *test* whether a pointer is "valid". C++ would incur significant performance penalties if a mechanism would be mandatory that could answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

You should not derive from a standard library class, they have no virtual destructor, they are not meant to be base classes.

Maybe it's not the problem you have, but it's good to known. Don't do it.

You can have a std::string as a composition from your wrapper class. Or, as I have found, not use any wrapper at all for std::string class that leads to more problems rather than solving some.

You can maybe use some external functions if you need some specific features like "trim" etc..

It's good to known that in the boost library a lot of string manipulation function exist.

Comment: Agree that it is often not a good idea to derive from the container classes, but the non-virtual destructor is a problem **only** if you delete a CustomStr through a pointer to std::string. Low risk, is my guess.